# VS 2017 for Android emulator not working - xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Installed VS 2017 (prof & community) RTM for xamarin development. Getting the below error while running the app. I have verified that installed the Intel Acceleration component. Any insights ?

```html
1>C:\Users\Sowmyan\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\App1\App1\App1.Android\App1.Android.csproj : warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for FormsViewGroup.dll (v7.1) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v6.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
1>C:\Users\Sowmyan\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\App1\App1\App1.Android\App1.Android.csproj : warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll (v7.1) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v6.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
1>C:\Users\Sowmyan\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\App1\App1\App1.Android\App1.Android.csproj : warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll (v7.1) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v6.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\toolbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\toolbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml
2>Starting deploy VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone ...
2>Starting emulator VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone ...
2>C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone -prop monodroid.avdname=VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone
**2>emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!**
2>Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
2>CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine
2>Emulator VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone cannot be started.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please add in SDK Manager in Extras "HAXM installer" and close the VS and emulator. If the error persists, try using Xamarin Android Player. It is very stable and fast.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my laptop.  It turned out the Virtualization was turned off in my BIOS.  My recommendation is to enter the BIOS setup on reboot   (refer to manual as all machines are different) and see if Intel Virtualization is enabled.  If not, you will need to enable it.